# Explanation of how to use Rawquery passing parameters

Tags: android, sqlite

I have three table in a SQLite database created in onCreate.
I have no data records only need to query the tables to make a calculation and display on the screen.
This is the sql I need to do to get 3 variables I need. The sql returns only one record is not a list.

```
 SELECT
        table1.nome,
        table1.valorinicial,
        table2.valorkm
    FROM
        table3
    INNER JOIN bandeira ON table1. ID = table3.bandeira_id
    INNER JOIN tarifacorrida ON table2. ID = table1.tarifacorrida_id
    WHERE
        ? BETWEEN table3.datainicio
    AND table3.datafim
    OR table3.datainicio <= ?
    AND table3.datafim IS NULL
    AND ? BETWEEN table3.horainicio
    AND table3.horafim
    AND ? = TRUE;
```

Rawquery researched and think it's the best solution, but did not understand how to run sql,as I pass these parameters to the sql and get the three variables I need, can someone explain to me in detail so I can understand and apply here?

```
  public ExampleVO getExample(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DB(ctx).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor rs = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        ExampleVO vo = null;

        if (rs.moveToFirst()){
            vo = new ExampleVO();
            vo.setValor(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("ColumnName")));


        }

        return vo;
    }
```

Comment: `? = TRUE` does not make sense. What are these parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just fill in the sql with parameters using String.format, and then you do not need arguments for rawQuery (the second argument will be null, as currently it is)

If you want to use arguments (sql with ? symbols), then args parameter needs to be a String array, for example:

```
Cursor cc = db.rawQuery("select col1 from table where col2=? and col3=?",new String[] { "value for col2", "value for col3" });
```

with String.format (**EDITED**: this is **incorrect** way, see comments below. So the only first case is a right one):

```
String sql = String.format("select col1 from table where col2=%s and col3=%s","value for col2", "value for col3");
Cursor cc = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Comment: example is completly wrong ... and `select col1 from table where col2=value for col2 and col3=value for col3` which would be produced by format is not valid SQL

Comment: @Selvin good point. Arguments needs to be encoded for string literals, to be 'completely right'

Comment: OK, it makes sense. Is my understanding correct that the case #1 (with arguments) is a right one?

Comment: yes, parameters will add '' for strings and sanitize 'em thats why it make no sense to compare simple string format with parameters